# Break For Each Loop in a Custom Cypress Command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a custom Cypress command to scroll through a list until you reach the item passed into the command. In my command I have `$.each` so I can compare the name of the item to the item name passed into the function. If they match then I send a click command which is "ENTER" in my environment.
I am able to successful scroll through the list and find the the item I am looking for and click on it but the loop continues to execute. I added `return false` which is what Cypress says should break the loop but it is now working for me. Any ideas why that is the case?

```
listItems.getChildren('OneLineTextElement', 'type').each(($elm) => {
    let labelAndValue = cy.wrap($elm).getChildren('LabelAndValue')
    let label = labelAndValue.getChild('Label')
    label.getProperty('texture-text').then(val => {
        if (val == subject) {
            cy.action('ENTER')
            return false
        }
        else {
            cy.action('DOWN')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you mean `return false` is not breaking the loop ?

Comment: Yes this is what cypress says should break the loop. Here is the documentation link: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early

Comment: Are you sure you are going inside the If block? if not,  place two `cy.log('if')` inside if block and `cy.log('else')` inside the else block to debug.

Comment: Yes I am entered the if block because the enter command gets executed but the .each loop continues to run on the next page

Comment: What I understand is the `return false` should be in the level of `each` for it to work. Since it is inside `label.getProperty('texture-text').then(val` its not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a control variable in the the scope of the `.each()` command.

```js
listItems.getChildren('OneLineTextElement', 'type').each(($elm) => {

  let done = false;

  let labelAndValue = cy.wrap($elm).getChildren('LabelAndValue')
  let label = labelAndValue.getChild('Label')
  label.getProperty('texture-text').then(val => {
    if (val == subject) {

      cy.action('ENTER').then(() => {  // is cy.action a custom command? 
                                       // Likely you may need to wait
        done = true;
      })
    } else {
      cy.action('DOWN')
    }
  })

  if (done) {
    return false;
  }  
})
```

However there are some method calls that look like custom commands inside `.each()` so you may not get the flow of execution you expect (Cypress commands and test javascript can run asynchronously).

It looks like the code may be refactored to avoid "scrolling through the list". The only thing this does not do is `cy.action('DOWN')` on the non-subject list items.

```js
listItems.getChildren('OneLineTextElement', 'type')
  .getChildren('LabelAndValue')
  .getChild('Label')
  .getProperty('texture-text')
  .should(val => {
    expect(val).to.equal(subject); 
    cy.action('ENTER');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use promise after finding your match within the loop, and then apply the assertion. Below an example searching value '23' within the column 8 which corresponds to age field.

```
cy.get('.column-8')
        .each(ele => {
            if (ele.text() === '23') {
                isValuePresent = true
                if (isValuePresent) return false
            }
        }).then(() => {
            expect(isValuePresent).to.be.true
        })
```